# How to export a class file into jar and use it in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Have a java file for creating some of my pre-requisite of my load test. And I am having a property file for some entry to this class file. I want to export this class file to runnable Jar and run it from JMeter to make the test independent (as I am running this java file manually every time before triggering the test).

How to integrate the property file with jar file ? like do I need to include the property file into the runnable jar? if yes how will pass variable to it from JMeter ?

Here is my Sample Java File,

```
package Automation.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.*;

public class ImageUtility {
    static List<String> stuName = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> sitName = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> subName = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> visName = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> modName = new ArrayList<String>();
    static String examDate[] = new String[10];

    static String envfilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\ENV_2.properties";
    static Properties p = new Properties();
    static int totalimages;
    static String stuVal = p.getProperty("StuValue");
    static String sitVal = p.getProperty("SitValue");
    static String subVal = p.getProperty("SubValue");
    static String visValue = p.getProperty("VisValue");
    static String Examdate = p.getProperty("Examdates");
    static String modVal = p.getProperty("ModValue");

    static String stuInstnaceUID;
    static String stuUUId;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            FileReader reader = new FileReader(envfilePath);
            p.load(reader);

            stuVal = p.getProperty("StuValue");
            sitVal = p.getProperty("SitValue");
            subVal = p.getProperty("SubValue");
            visValue = p.getProperty("VisValue");
            Examdate = p.getProperty("Examdates");
            modVal = p.getProperty("ModValue");
            stuInstnaceUID = p.getProperty("stuInstnaceUIDValue") + p.getProperty("SubValue") + "0";
            File[] files = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\generated\\").listFiles();
            int subN = Integer.parseInt(p.getProperty("SubValue"));

            for (String sName : stuName) {
                for (String siName : sitName) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < (Integer.parseInt(p.getProperty("NoOfSubjectsValue"))); i++) {
                        stuInstnaceUID = p.getProperty("stuInstnaceUIDValue") + subN + "0";
                        stuUUId = p.getProperty("StuUUIdValue") + subN;
                        for (String vName : visName) {
                            if (vName.equals("baseline") || vName.equals("PRE_TREATMENT")) {
                                Examdate = examDate[0];
                            } else if (vName.equals("cycle_1")) {
                                Examdate = examDate[1];
                            } else if (vName.equals("cycle_2")) {
                                Examdate = examDate[2];
                            } else if (vName.equals("cycle_3")) {
                                Examdate = examDate[3];
                            }
                            for (String modtxt : modName) {

                            }
                        }
                        subN++;
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

And Sample property file:

```
StuValue=555210
SitValue=98141
SubValue=98167
NoOfSubjectsValue=1
VisValue=baseline
NoofImagesPerVisit=1
ModValue=ct
Examdates=20160616

stuInstnaceUIDValue=1.333.148.217134.
StuUUIdValue=2.25.282782546287287271988767684395420443
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what do you want to achieve:

1. You can run your executable .jar using [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter)
2. You can copy the code into [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and call it where required
3. You can put your .jar into [JMeter ClassPath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and invoke it from the JSR223 Sampler where required.